# add LDAP slave to N-way multimaster system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openldap

I have 2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS servers running Openldap 2.5 in N-way multimaster mode.  It works great and has for several years.  Now I'd like to add a slave to this system.  The two multimaster nodes do NOT use TLS, and both use cn=admin,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com account for binding/synchronization.  Not ideal as the LDAP admin password is passed back and forth in plain text all day but the machines sync on their own private vlan.

However, with new slaves I'd like to use TLS/SSL.

I set up a CA, generated some certs and installed them on one of the masters and on my slave.  Both now can process STARTTLS requests.  So far so good.

I created a user "replicator" on the master and assigned this user a password.  I specified that the replicator account is the account to bind for sync transfers on the slave.

I need to add an acl rule on the master so that "replicator" has read access to the user database.  So, I add:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact "cn=replicator,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com" read by * break
```

to both my main database "dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config" and my accesslog database "dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config" on the master.  Once added, the acl's for both DB's look correct, there's just a new rule that's evaluated first (rule {0}).

Now, here's where things get weird.  Once these rules are in place, my (single) master and the new slave start syncing and quickly show the same contextCSN value.  However, at this point my two masters are no longer syncing.  I need to remove these "replicator" user rules and restart slapd on the master to re-establish sync with the other master.  I have made no changes to either master other than to add the single ACL entry for replicator read access to the 2 DB's on one of the masters.

Any suggestions as to what's going on or where I might look for more info?  This is a production environment so there are limited windows to take either master offline.

Any suggestions appreciated.